# How to use unicode in C

Tags: c, unicode

I just switched over from using HTML to C, and in HTML it's really easy to use unicode. So I was wondering if there was a way to use unicode in C? Are there any code libraries?

Comment: You know HTML and C are not interchangeable, right? You can't "switch" from one to the other.

Comment: I understand that, but I was wondering if there was a way in C, HTML was an example @EugeneSh.

Comment: I read that article @cdarke, but it didn't really make sense to me

Comment: Read @Jonathan Leffler's reply, that is comprehensive, in particular **C11 and <uchar.h>**.  Are you sure you are experienced enough with C to do this?

Comment: Is thsi a complicated procedure? I started C three months ago, so I don't thnik that i am experienced

Comment: If the available *general* answer(s) do not make sense to you, then you should probably consider asking more specific questions.

Comment: Ok, thanks @JohnBollinger, will do